# TcxGrid Auto posting if another row is focused?

Tags: delphi, grid, devexpress

I'm using Delphi the devexpress components.
I'm running into a annoying problem where the grid seems to call a postdata if I'm inserting a new row and then accidently click on a different row.

I'm not sure the TcxGrid is doing this but I want to know if there is a property I could set to prevent this from happening?

Comment: That behaviour is as designed. The grid cannot tell whether you meant to click on another row, or did so by accident.

Comment: It is the usual behavior of data grids and I don't think there is such an option. Otherwise the grid would have to keep a lot of change information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As fas as this is not a problem of the grid, but of the dataset, the only way to intervene is preveting a post for conditions you have to define.

```
procedure TForm.aDatasetBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
   if YourConditionForInvaliddata then
     begin
       Dataset.Cancel;
       Abort;
     end;
end;
```

Comment: You rather meant `DataSet.Cancel` instead of `Ads.Cancel`, don't you ?